# Preprocessor output fields

Tags: c, gcc

i have these lines in preprocesor output.

......

- 1 "test.c"
- 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
- 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3
- 4 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
- 374 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4

......

i got to know that at line 27 in stdio.h there is a call to include features.h but what does the other numbers 1,3,4 in both these line defines.
can anyone explain what exactly these different field means little elaborately.

as you see

1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4

27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4

why two inclusion of stdio.h or if i am wrong what does that means?

Answer (score 1):

From gcc [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html):

> Source file name and line number information is conveyed by lines of
> the form
>
> **# linenum filename flags**
>
> These are called linemarkers. They are inserted as needed into the output (but never within a string or
> character constant). They mean that the following line originated in
> file filename at line linenum. filename will never contain any
> non-printing characters; they are replaced with octal escape
> sequences.
>
> After the file name comes **zero or more flags**, which are ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’,
> or ‘4’. If there are multiple flags, spaces separate them. Here is
> what the flags mean:
>
> ‘1’ This indicates the start of a new file.
>
> ‘2’ This indicates returning to a file (after having included another file).
>
> ‘3’ This indicates that the following text comes from a system header file, so
> certain warnings should be suppressed.
>
> ‘4’ This indicates that the following text should be treated as being wrapped in an implicit extern "C" block.

Comment: Thanks. so from above explanation it states that, 1 "test.c" defines that the line below this is originated from test.c at line 1. so the next line 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4 states that this is the start of a new file and the line below is originated from "/usr/include/stdio.h" at line 1 having system headers and should be treated as being wrapped in implicit extern C block? But is 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4 line really originated from line 1 of "/usr/include/stdio.h"?..

Comment: i am trying to understand it literally but i am little confused that the same 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4 is originated from /usr/include/stdio.h file, How?